# Single-row grid with height 1fr not filling height in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid inside a Flexbox column, and the grid has `flex-grow: 1`.

In Chrome, the grid expands to fill available space, but its content does not, even with `align-content: stretch` on the grid. In Firefox and Edge, the content expands to fill the grid's height, as desired.

[Here's a pen that reproduces the problem](https://codepen.io/FTWinston/pen/BJgEOR?editors=1100), and images of how it looks in different browsers. Is this a bug with Chrome, and if so, can anyone suggest a straightforward workaround?

**Chrome**

[image: Pen in chrome, showing the bug]

**Firefox**

[image: Pen in firefox, showing desired behaviour]

**Edge**

[image: Pen in edge, showing desired behaviour]

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 15rem;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#grid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  background-color: #ccf;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-content: stretch; /* "end" correctly puts the row to the bottom */
}

#left {
  background-color: #fcc;
}

#right {
  background-color: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top">not in grid</div>

  <div id="grid">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not use _height_ to fix _a Flexbox issue_, use one of its own properties if possible, as suggested by Michael, or else, when/if Chrome get that bug/behavior solved, your solution might suddenly break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this a bug with Chrome, and if so, can anyone suggest a straightforward workaround?

It looks like a bug in Chrome. But I can't say for sure.

Here's what's happening:

- You have the flex item grid container set to consume all available height with `flex-grow: 1`
- Because you've only defined the `flex-grow` property, the other two [flexibility properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components) – `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` – remain at their default values.
- The default value of `flex-shrink` is `1`, and is not pertinent to this problem.
- The default value of `flex-basis` is `auto`, *and is the source of the problem*.
- If you add `flex-basis: 0` to your code, the item takes full height in Chrome, as well.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdVeLm?editors=1100)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 15rem;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#grid {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  flex: 1; /* fg:1, fs:1, fb:0 */
  display: grid;
  background-color: #ccf;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

#left  { background-color: #fcc; }
#right { background-color: #cfc; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top">not in grid</div>
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```